# I'm trying to use multiple output callbacks in dash, but it only shows one output, and the rest of the charts are blank

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I tried to put all of the outputs in one function that updates for multiple outputs with a single callback, as written in the code below. However,the dashboard only shows the first chart and the rest show up as blank. The code compiles and runs.
 To experiment, I tried to change the layout of the app and the order of the callback, but the most that would do is show a display on a different chart on the dashboard rather than the first one. The only part of the function that gets displayed is the revenue variable, which is the first declared within the function.I took an approach to use multiple outputs, and declare all variables one by one within the function, and then return them in one line. I just need to figure out what I need to have all of the outputs working.
The interval callback isn't being used for now, as I planned to use that later to update data that will be scraped from a site.
 I've added the relevant code below as well as a screenshot of the how the dashboard looks. 
[Link to dashboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3F26.png)

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data=pd.read_csv('C:\sepdata.csv')



df=data[['date','symbol','shares','anet pl']]



#calculates total revenues
def calculate_revs(x):

#calculates total costs
def calculate_costs(x):

#average revenue
def calculate_arpt(x):

#average cost
def calculate_acpt(x):

#revenue standard deviation
def calculate_revstd(x):

#cost standard deviation
def calculate_coststd(x):

#income/costs
def calculate_netmargin(x):

#takes in other functions to return trailing length series
def mastercalc(df,length,function):
    start=len(df)-length
    end=len(df)
    mainlist=[]
    for i in range(0,100):
        s=start-i
        e=end-i
        d=df[s:e]
        mainlist.append(function(d))
    return mainlist


app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='total-revenues', style={'width': '50.1%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='total-costs', style={'width': '49.9%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='net-margin', style={'width': '100%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='arpt', style={'width': '50.1%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='acpt', style={'width': '49.9%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='revstd', style={'width': '50.1%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='coststd', style={'width': '49.9%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
    dcc.Interval(id='interval', interval=3000, n_intervals=0)
    ])

@app.callback([Output('total-revenues', 'figure'),
               Output('total-costs','figure'),
               Output('net-margin','figure'),
               Output('arpt','figure'),
               Output('acpt','figure'),
               Output('revstd','figure'),
               Output('coststd','figure')],
              [Input('interval', 'n_intervals')])
def upd_figs(n):
    x = np.arange(1, 101)
    revs = mastercalc(df, 100, calculate_revs)
    data = go.Bar(
        x=list(x),
        y=list(reversed(revs)),
        opacity=0.70,
        marker={'color': 'rgb(0,180,0)'}
    )

    revenues= {
        'data': [data],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            xaxis={'title': 'Trailing Number', 'range': [min(list(x)), max(list(x))]},
            yaxis={'title': 'Total Revenues', 'range': [0.8 * min(list(revs)), 1.2 * max(list(revs))]},
            margin={'l': 40, 't': 40, 'b': 30, 'r': 20},
            hovermode='closest',
            plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            paper_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            font={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)'}
            # transition={'duration':1000}
        )
    }

    #costs
    xC = np.arange(1, 101)
    cost = mastercalc(df, 100, calculate_costs)
    dataC = go.Bar(
        x=list(xC),
        y=list(reversed(cost)),
        opacity=0.70,
        marker={'color': 'rgb(180,0,0)'}
    )

    costs= {
        'data': [dataC],
        'layout': dict(
            xaxis={'title': 'Trailing Number', 'range': [min(list(x)), max(list(x))]},
            yaxis={'title': 'Total Costs', 'range': [1.2 * min(list(revs)), 0.8 * max(list(revs))]},
            margin={'l': 40, 't': 40, 'b': 30, 'r': 20},
            hovermode='closest',
            plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            paper_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            font={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)'}
            # transition={'duration':1000}
        )
    }

    #netmargin
    nm = mastercalc(df, 100, calculate_netmargin)
    data = go.Bar(
        x=list(x),
        y=list(reversed(nm)),
        opacity=0.70,
        marker={'color': 'rgb(153,216,240)'}
    )

    netmargin= {
        'data': [data],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            xaxis={'title': 'Trailing Number', 'range': [min(list(x)), max(list(x))]},
            yaxis={'title': 'Net Margin Ratio', 'range': [0.8 * min(list(revs)), 1.2 * max(list(revs))]},
            margin={'l': 40, 't': 40, 'b': 30, 'r': 20},
            hovermode='closest',
            plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            paper_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            font={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)'}
            # transition={'duration':1000}
        )
    }


    #arpt
    rpt = mastercalc(df, 100, calculate_arpt)
    data = go.Bar(
        x=list(x),
        y=list(reversed(rpt)),
        opacity=0.70,
        marker={'color': 'rgb(0,180,0)'}
    )

    arpt= {
        'data': [data],
        'layout': dict(
            xaxis={'title': 'Trailing Number', 'range': [min(list(x)), max(list(x))]},
            yaxis={'title': 'ARPT', 'range': [0.8 * min(list(revs)), 1.2 * max(list(revs))]},
            margin={'l': 40, 't': 40, 'b': 30, 'r': 20},
            hovermode='closest',
            plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            paper_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            font={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)'}
            # transition={'duration':1000}
        )
    }


    #acpt
    cpt = mastercalc(df, 100, calculate_acpt)
    data = go.Bar(
        x=list(x),
        y=list(reversed(cpt)),
        opacity=0.70,
        marker={'color': 'rgb(180,0,0)'}
    )

    acpt= {
        'data': [data],
        'layout': dict(
            xaxis={'title': 'Number', 'range': [min(list(x)), max(list(x))]},
            yaxis={'title': 'ACPT', 'range': [1.2 * min(list(revs)), 0.8 * max(list(revs))]},
            margin={'l': 40, 't': 40, 'b': 30, 'r': 20},
            hovermode='closest',
            plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            paper_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            font={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)'}
            # transition={'duration':1000}
        )
    }

    #revstd
    rstd = mastercalc(df, 100, calculate_revstd)

    data = go.Scatter(
        x=list(x),
        y=list(reversed(rstd)),
        mode='lines+markers',
        opacity=0.70,
        marker={'color': 'rgb(0,180,0)'}
    )
    revstd= {
        'data': [data],
        'layout': dict(
            xaxis={'title': 'Number', 'range': [min(list(x)), max(list(x))]},
            yaxis={'title': 'Rev Stdev', 'range': [0.8 * min(list(revs)), 1.2 * max(list(revs))]},
            margin={'l': 40, 't': 40, 'b': 30, 'r': 20},
            hovermode='closest',
            plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            paper_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            font={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)'}
            # transition={'duration':1000}
        )
    }


    #coststd
    cstd = mastercalc(df, 100, calculate_coststd)
    data = go.Scatter(
        x=list(x),
        y=list(reversed(cstd)),
        mode='lines+markers',
        opacity=0.70,
        marker={'color': 'rgb(180,0,0)'}
    )
    coststd= {
        'data': [data],
        'layout': dict(
            xaxis={'title': 'Number', 'range': [min(list(x)), max(list(x))]},
            yaxis={'title': 'Cost Stdev', 'range': [1.2 * min(list(revs)), 0.8 * max(list(revs))]},
            margin={'l': 40, 't': 40, 'b': 30, 'r': 20},
            hovermode='closest',
            plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            paper_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',
            font={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)'}
            # transition={'duration':1000}
        )
    }
    return revenues,costs,netmargin,arpt,acpt,revstd,coststd


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant have multiple Outputs in one callback
You can have multiple Inputs in a callback for one output

so basically for each output you would need a separate callback

EDIT: Dash 0.39 allows multiple outputs